# How to use MutationAction in vuex-module-decorators?

Tags: typescript, vuex

I'm trying to use vuex-module-decorators from https://championswimmer.in/vuex-module-decorators.
Let's say my module's state has a prop `dir` that's a dict: `{[key: string]: string}` Can I use `@MutationAction` to update an element of that dict? The code below isn't right but hopefully gets across what I mean.

```js
export default class Module extends VuexModule {
  dir: {[key: string]: string}

  @MutationAction(???)
  updateDir(keyValue) {
    return keyValue // ???
  }
}
```

Is there some doc on how to use `@MutationAction`, what args it takes and what actual mutation it commits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what you should be doing -

```
export default class Module extends VuexModule {
  dir: {[key: string]: string}

  @MutationAction(['dir'])
  async updateDir(keyValue) {
    const currDir = this.dir

    // do any async work (network req) here
    currDir['myKey'] = keyValue

    return ( { dir: currDir } )
  }
}
```

But if you really did not need to any async work in the first place.

```
export default class Module extends VuexModule {
  dir: {[key: string]: string}

  @Mutation
  async updateDir(keyValue) {
    this.dir.myKey = keyValue
  }
}
```

P.S. I am the author of `vuex-module-decorators`

Comment: Thanks -- it would be great if the doc had a more detailed section on how to use `@MutationAction` -- exactly what it does internally, what to return, does it update vs. replace, how to handle errors.

Comment: How can you access the module state without using this.state.foo ?

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie with vuex, anyway, this compiles:

```
export class MyModule extends VuexModule {

    public dir: { [key: string]: string } = {};

    @MutationAction({ mutate: ['dir'] })
    public async updateDir(key: string, value: string) {
        const newDir: { [key: string]: string } = {};
        newDir[key] = value;
        return {
            dir: newDir,
        };
    }

    @MutationAction({ mutate: ['dir'] })
    public async addToDir(key: string, value: string) {
        this.dir[key] = value;
        return {
            dir: this.dir,
        };
    }
}
```

Please note that I don't know if it is acceptable to modify and reassign the 'dir' variable as I do in the second function.

Comment: Pretty sure you're not supposed to modify state outside of a mutator.

Comment: @GaryO Indeed, in fact, in my code, I am doing it inside a mutator.

Comment: that may be, but in the code you show above, you're doing it in an action. A function decorated with `@MutationAction` is actually the action; it's supposed to return something (?) which will be used in a generated mutation. At least that's my understanding.